# Magentoc XML RCP - [2] Access denied

Tags: magento, xml-rpc

I am trying to request a list of orders from Magento using the C# XML RPC Api. When I request a list of orders, I get this error:

Server returned a fault exception: [2] Access denied.

I have performed these steps:

1. System > Web Services > XML RPC Users
2. Created a user and assigned them to the administrator role

The client is using Magento 1.702. I can login fine through the API, just not access orders.

```
        // login (make sure you have user and role assigned in magento admin)
        string sessionId = Connection.Login(apiUrl, apiUser, apiPass);

        var soList = Order.List(apiUrl, sessionId, new object[] { });

        Console.ReadLine();
```

In the site, I went to System > Web Services > XML RPC Roles and I clicked on a role. I receive an error screen. I wonder if this has something do with it.

Here is the library:

https://code.google.com/p/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi/downloads/list

Comment: Repots from your error log would help.  There's no such thing as a "blank screen". An error was spewed somewhere.

Comment: How do I access the error log?

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new web services role called WS2. For permissions, I made sure that all was selected.